# how to solve invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘char’) error?

Tags: c++

Running the code snippet below, generates this output error. can somebody explain **WHY**?

**Output Error**

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘char’)
         if(* i =='<')
```

**The Code**

```
string a;
    for(auto i:a)
    {
        cout<< i <<endl;
        if(*i=='<')
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i` is already a character no dereferencing needed. use `i == '<'`.

Comment: auto resolves to a char,not char*. Also a reason why auto isn't a good keyword in most instances. This case is easy, but most inherited virtual cases it becomes hard for readability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understanding the error:**

> `error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘char’)`

Unary operator is an operator with only one operand. In this case it is `*`. It has an invalid argument i.e., `char`.

Because a `std::string` contains `char`s and not `char*`. So :

```
if(*i=='<')
```

`*i` is `char` here. When you dereference it, you get the error. Remove the `*` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dereference  i.
Removing the asterisk fixes the error.

```
if(i=='<')
{
  //...
}
```